# Using custom root CA with HttpClient

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, ca

In C#, when using HttpClient, how can I connect to the https server that is using either self-signed certificate (for testing) or a custom CA that is not part of the machine's trust-store?  Note that I m not needing client certificates, only need HttpClient to validate the server certificate that is not signed by one of the trusted root CA on the machine.  I know that i could just add the self-signed certificate or the CA to the local trust-store on the machine, but let's say I want to avoid doing this.  What i need is basically to supply extra root CA to the running application.

There are quite simple ways to do this in other languages as I know:

1. In java, using "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" system property.
2. In Node.js, using NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERT environment variable.

But I couldn't find anything like this for .Net so far.  Is there a simple way like the above?

Comment: There is a callback to validate server certificate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=net-5.0

Comment: Oh i see, thanks. But i m still wondering if there is a simple way like above (e.g. through env variable) to avoid rewriting the whole logic of certificate validation.  Basically use built-in validation but consider the certificate(s) i supply for the process to be one of the root certificates.

Comment: I'm not aware of any

Answer (score 2):

I fought with this for a while, there don't seem to be good answers out there other than "write your own callback handler" as user evk mentioned with the link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=net-5.0 in the comments above, but that doesn't really explain what should be inside that callback. Then I stumbled upon this comment https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39835#issuecomment-663020581

Turns out, using a custom root cert is pretty straight forward. Basically, alter the chain policy to use custom roots, add your custom root, and call build on the chain.

```
private static bool ServerCertificateCustomValidation(
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage,
    X509Certificate2? certificate,
    X509Chain? chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslErrors)
{
    if (certificate == null) return false;
    if (chain == null) return false;
    chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(GetTrustedRootCert());
    return chain.Build(certificate);
}
```

Keep in mind you may still want to check some other things, like if there are other policy errors. This answer only covers the using a custom trusted root.

Comment: Any alternate for donet 3.1?